# Programmatically create a button with a gradient stroke?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I am working on a creating a button with no fill, but a gradient stroke. For reference, here is the end result I am after:

[image]

I would like to know how to create such a button with a gradient stroke and no fill programmatically. I looked over `GradientDrawable` class and the `setStroke()` method in it. None seem to allow this. Is there any way to programmatically perform this or is it not possible at all?

Comment: yes it is possible...have you tried with drawable ? and what do you mean by `gradient stroke and no fill programmatically`

Comment: No can you show an example?

Comment: @Vivek did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15563761/programmatically-add-gradient-with-solid-color-and-stroke

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145131/trying-to-draw-a-button-how-to-set-a-stroke-color-and-how-to-align-a-gradient

Comment: @NileshRathod Thanks for responding! I checked and both examples use a single color as stroke. What I want is a gradient as the stroke color.

Comment: @Mohit Thanks for responding. I haven't tried Drawable. Can you show an example? 
If you look closely in the picture I added. The stroke is a gradient (i.e. gradient stroke). Also, the button itself is transparent (i.e. No fill).

Comment: have you checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27692701/multi-color-stroke-image-with-xml)

Comment: @jubayer Thanks! But that is done with XML. I want to achieve it programmatically!

Comment: Why programmatically? That would be a time waster!

Comment: @KlingKlang I was making a custom button in which I can always set the corner radius to half the variable height in order to scale properly, maintain different states etc. Can you explain why it is a time waster?

Comment: @Vivek programmatically? then simply create a custom `Drawable` class and override its `draw(Canvas)` method (and possibly `isStateful`, `setState` or `setLevel`)

Comment: Because you waste time in calculations, rather than letting Android use its own optimized code for that. Having a drawable to manage is more easily handled by the system.

Comment: and no, DO NOT even try to do that in XML - its a waste of your time

Comment: @pskink Can you show an example of the gradient stroke part with `Drawable`?

Comment: see `Paint#setShader`

Comment: @pskink let me check that

Comment: @Vivek have u check my answer ??

Comment: @Mohit I am checking it. Thanks, Mohit I was also playing with `Drawable` when you posted your answer. Will update soon!

Comment: @Mohit It worked!!! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Vivek your welcome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tried something for you..
Use  `mRect.set` to set path and `mPath.addRoundRect`add rectangle.Use `setShader` for strock purpose [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8600845/2553431)

Drawable class:

```
public class CustomDrawable extends Drawable {
Paint mPaint;
int startColor, endColor, mBorderWidth, mBorderRadius;
RectF mRect;
Path mPath;

public CustomDrawable(int startColor, int endColor, int borderWidth, int borderRadius) {
    mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    mPath = new Path();
    mPath.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);

    mRect = new RectF();
    this.startColor = startColor;
    this.endColor = endColor;

    mBorderWidth = borderWidth;
    mBorderRadius = borderRadius;
}

@Override
protected void onBoundsChange(Rect bounds) {
    super.onBoundsChange(bounds);
    mPath.reset();

    // out rect
    mRect.set(bounds.left + mBorderWidth, bounds.top + mBorderWidth, bounds.right - mBorderWidth, bounds.bottom - mBorderWidth);
    mPath.addRoundRect(mRect, mBorderRadius, mBorderRadius, Path.Direction.CW);

    // inner rect
    mRect.set(bounds.left + 20, bounds.top + 20, bounds.right - 20, bounds.bottom - 20);
    mPath.addRoundRect(mRect, mBorderRadius, mBorderRadius, Path.Direction.CW);
}

@Override
public void draw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
    // kind of strock 
    mPaint.setShader(new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 100, startColor, endColor, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR));
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
}
@Override
public void setAlpha(int alpha) { mPaint.setAlpha(alpha);}
@Override
public void setColorFilter(@Nullable ColorFilter colorFilter) {mPaint.setColorFilter(colorFilter);}
@Override
public int getOpacity() {return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;}
}
```

Main :

```
Button but = ((Button)findViewById(R.id.but));
but.setBackground(new CustomDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FD659B"),
       Color.parseColor("#F76E63"),
       but.getPaddingLeft(), 100));
```

layout :

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/but"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="Signin"/>
```

Comment: no need for `CustomButton` - just use `View#setBackground` method

Comment: @pskink thank buddy for your suggestion.. I have updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is a further step from what @lamat8 contributed:

```
import android.graphics.*
import android.graphics.Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG
import android.graphics.Path.FillType
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
import androidx.annotation.NonNull
import java.lang.RuntimeException


class GradientDrawable(
    private var strokeStartColor: Int,
    private var strokeEndColor: Int,
    private var fillStartColor: Int,
    private var fillEndColor: Int,
    private var strokeWidth: Float,
    private var radius: Float,
    private var strokeGradientDirection: Direction,
    private var fillGradientDirection: Direction
) : Drawable() {

    enum class Direction {
        LEFT_RIGHT,
        TOP_BOTTOM,
        RIGHT_LEFT,
        BOTTOM_TOP,
        TL_BR,
        TR_BL,
        BR_TL,
        BL_TR
    }

    private val strokePaint: Paint = Paint(ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)
    private val fillPaint: Paint = Paint(ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)
    private val strokeOuterRect = RectF()
    private val fillRect = RectF()
    private val path = Path()

    init {
        strokePaint.style = Paint.Style.FILL
        path.fillType = FillType.EVEN_ODD
    }

    override fun onBoundsChange(bounds: Rect) {
        super.onBoundsChange(bounds)

        path.reset()

        strokeOuterRect.set(bounds)
        fillRect.set(
            bounds.left + strokeWidth,
            bounds.top + strokeWidth,
            bounds.right - strokeWidth,
            bounds.bottom - strokeWidth
        )

        path.addRoundRect(
            strokeOuterRect,
            radius,
            radius,
            Path.Direction.CW
        )

        path.addRoundRect(
            fillRect,
            radius,
            radius,
            Path.Direction.CW
        )
    }

    override fun draw(@NonNull canvas: Canvas) {
        var x0: Float
        var y0: Float
        var x1: Float
        var y1: Float

        // drawing the stroke

        when (strokeGradientDirection) {
            Direction.LEFT_RIGHT -> {
                x0 = strokeOuterRect.left
                y0 = strokeOuterRect.centerY()
                x1 = strokeOuterRect.right
                y1 = strokeOuterRect.centerY()
            }
            Direction.TOP_BOTTOM -> {
                x0 = strokeOuterRect.centerX()
                y0 = strokeOuterRect.top
                x1 = strokeOuterRect.centerX()
                y1 = strokeOuterRect.bottom
            }
            Direction.RIGHT_LEFT -> {
                x0 = strokeOuterRect.right
                y0 = strokeOuterRect.centerY()
                x1 = strokeOuterRect.left
                y1 = strokeOuterRect.centerY()
            }
            Direction.BOTTOM_TOP -> {
                x0 = strokeOuterRect.centerX()
                y0 = strokeOuterRect.bottom
                x1 = strokeOuterRect.centerX()
                y1 = strokeOuterRect.top
            }
            Direction.TL_BR -> {
                x0 = strokeOuterRect.left
                y0 = strokeOuterRect.top
                x1 = strokeOuterRect.right
                y1 = strokeOuterRect.bottom
            }
            Direction.TR_BL -> {
                x0 = strokeOuterRect.right
                y0 = strokeOuterRect.top
                x1 = strokeOuterRect.left
                y1 = strokeOuterRect.bottom
            }
            Direction.BR_TL -> {
                x0 = strokeOuterRect.right
                y0 = strokeOuterRect.bottom
                x1 = strokeOuterRect.left
                y1 = strokeOuterRect.top
            }
            Direction.BL_TR -> {
                x0 = strokeOuterRect.left
                y0 = strokeOuterRect.bottom
                x1 = strokeOuterRect.right
                y1 = strokeOuterRect.top
            }
        }

        strokePaint.shader = LinearGradient(
            x0,
            y0,
            x1,
            y1,
            strokeStartColor,
            strokeEndColor,
            Shader.TileMode.MIRROR
        )

        canvas.drawPath(path, strokePaint)

        // filling the shape

        when (fillGradientDirection) {
            Direction.LEFT_RIGHT -> {
                x0 = fillRect.left
                y0 = fillRect.centerY()
                x1 = fillRect.right
                y1 = fillRect.centerY()
            }
            Direction.TOP_BOTTOM -> {
                x0 = fillRect.centerX()
                y0 = fillRect.top
                x1 = fillRect.centerX()
                y1 = fillRect.bottom
            }
            Direction.RIGHT_LEFT -> {
                x0 = fillRect.right
                y0 = fillRect.centerY()
                x1 = fillRect.left
                y1 = fillRect.centerY()
            }
            Direction.BOTTOM_TOP -> {
                x0 = fillRect.centerX()
                y0 = fillRect.bottom
                x1 = fillRect.centerX()
                y1 = fillRect.top
            }
            Direction.TL_BR -> {
                x0 = fillRect.left
                y0 = fillRect.top
                x1 = fillRect.right
                y1 = fillRect.bottom
            }
            Direction.TR_BL -> {
                x0 = fillRect.right
                y0 = fillRect.top
                x1 = fillRect.left
                y1 = fillRect.bottom
            }
            Direction.BR_TL -> {
                x0 = fillRect.right
                y0 = fillRect.bottom
                x1 = fillRect.left
                y1 = fillRect.top
            }
            Direction.BL_TR -> {
                x0 = fillRect.left
                y0 = fillRect.bottom
                x1 = fillRect.right
                y1 = fillRect.top
            }
        }

        fillPaint.shader = LinearGradient(
            x0,
            y0,
            x1,
            y1,
            fillStartColor,
            fillEndColor,
            Shader.TileMode.MIRROR
        )

        canvas.drawRoundRect(
            fillRect,
            radius,
            radius,
            fillPaint
        )
    }

    override fun setAlpha(alpha: Int) {
        strokePaint.alpha = alpha
        fillPaint.alpha = alpha

        invalidateSelf()
    }

    override fun setColorFilter(colorFilter: ColorFilter?) {
        throw RuntimeException("Color filter cannot be set to this Drawable")
    }

    override fun getOpacity(): Int {
        return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
    }

    fun setStrokeColors(startColor: Int, endColor: Int) {
        this.strokeStartColor = startColor
        this.strokeEndColor = endColor

        invalidateSelf()
    }

    fun setFillColors(startColor: Int, endColor: Int) {
        this.fillStartColor = startColor
        this.fillEndColor = endColor

        invalidateSelf()
    }

    fun setRadius(radius: Float) {
        this.radius = radius

        invalidateSelf()
    }

    fun setStrokeWidth(width: Float) {
        this.strokeWidth = width

        invalidateSelf()
    }
}
```

That class adds the following features:

- direction to the stroke gradient;
- fill gradient, and;
- direction to the fill gradient;

Answer (score -1):

I don't think we can set gradient for Stroke but we can hack for the same using layer list.

you can create below drawable xml with the gradient you wanted

```
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <!-- gradient for the stroke is set below -->
        <gradient
            android:angle="180"
            android:startColor="#555994"
            android:endColor="#b5b6d2"
            android:type="linear" />
        <corners android:radius="4dp"></corners>
    </shape>

</item>
<!-- stroke width has to be adjusted by setting left, right , top and bottom -->
<item android:left="4dp" android:right="4dp"
    android:top="4dp" android:bottom="4dp">
    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

you can set the above drawable in layout/programmatically

***button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_background);***

Comment: This isn't programmatic and it doesn't provide a transparent background either